# Регулярное выражение для получения частей строк

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, в ней есть много подстрок типа `/dream/aim/`.
Как выдернуть `aim` и далее всё, что заключено в слэши после `dream`?
Что-то пытался наваять, не фурычит:

```
preg_match_all("/\/dream\/(*\w)\//", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: * - любое количество вхождений предшествующего символа или подмаски. В том числе и ноль.

Comment: Полностью пример строки и что нужно приведите

Comment: `preg_match_all("~/dream/([^/]+)~", $string, $matches); print_r($matches[1]);`

Comment: Подошло моё выражение?

Answer (score 0):

Можно и попроще:

```
$data = array_slice(explode('/', "/dream/aim/preg"),2);
var_dump($data);
```

Результат:

```
C:\wamp64\www\2017\17_03_02_sscanf\index.php:3:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'aim' (length=3)
  1 => string 'preg' (length=4)
```